# Property decorator without object attribute

Tags: python, class, object

I have a class like this that contains property but doesn't have corresponding attribute:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, csv_dict):
        self._csv_dict = csv_dict

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self["name"]

    @property
    def number(self):
        try:
            return round(float(self["number"]), 2)
        except ValueError:
            return None

    def __getitem__(self, field_name):
        value = self._csv_dict.get(field_name)
        if value:
            value = value.strip()
        return value
```

I'm trying to modify number but I can't seem to set it. Tried this:

```
example.number.setter(5)
```

this:

```
@number.setter
def number(self, new_number):
   self._number = new_number
   # and this self.number = new_number

example.number = 5
```

Getting these errors:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'setter
AtributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: The setter has to be inside the class, is it?

Comment: `self["number"]` isn't going to work. `self` is not a dictionary. Shouldn't that be `self._number`?

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I added additional piece. Basically, I'm just trying to modify number property in existing object but changing it returns errors

Comment: @Barmar yes, inside the class, which I tried but it didn't work

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me. Please post a [mre].

Comment: what worked? example.number.setter(5) or example.number = 5 with setter method?

Comment: `example.number = 5`

Comment: I added your `__getitem__` and the setter still works. But `print(example.number)` gets an error `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'NoneType'` because the setter doesn't add to the dictionary.

Comment: Be careful with your logic. Getter: `example.number` you access `example["number"]` Setter: `example.number` you access `example._number`. You want to access/modify the same object in both cases.

Comment: I have a feeling you don't really understand properties, since `example.number.setter` doesn't make any sense (accessing it manually, that is), and I don't know why you're assigning to `self._number` if that attribute doesn't already exist. Plus `value.strip()` won't work if `value` is an int. So I'm not sure how to help exactly other than recommending you do a tutorial on properties. Or if you can turn this into a *specific question*, please do; see [ask].

Comment: ... For example, maybe what you want to ask is "How can I make a property whose target is not an object attribute?"

Answer (score 0):

You getting and setting should (in a logical case) point to the same object. So you want to modify your underlying source dictionary.

You can either hardcode your setter to access the dictionary or also add a `__setitem__` logical.

```
class Example: 
  ...
  @number.setter
  def number(self, new_number):
     self["number"] = new_number  # a __setitem__
     # or:
     self._csv_dict["number"] = new_number # hardcoded without a __setitem__
     
  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
      self._csv_dict[key] = value
```

Note: At the current point your `Example` class could be an actual dictionary, so a child of `dict` and does not need to be wrapped around a dictionary.